# Combining two csv files together in perl

Tags: perl, csv

Hi i'm very new to perl and i've got litle knowledge on it but i'm trying to create a script that conbines two .csv files into a new one

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my @rows;
{   # Read the CSV file
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new() or die "Cannot use Text::CSV_XS ($!)";
    my $file = "file.csv";
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
    while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
        push @rows, $row;
    }
    $csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
    close $fh or die "Failed to close $file ($!)";
}

{    # Gather the data
    foreach my $row (@rows) {
        foreach my $col (@{$row}) {
            $col = uc($col);
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
# (over)Write the data 
#  Needs to be changed to ADD data
{
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, escape_char => undef })
        or die "Cannot use Text::CSV ($!)";
    my $file = "output.csv";
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
    $csv->eol("\n");
    foreach my $row (@rows) {
        $csv->print($fh, \@{$row}) or die "Failed to write $file ($!)";
    }
    close $fh or die "Failed to close $file ($!)";
}
```

this is my current code i do know this over write's the data insted of actually adding it to the new file but this is how far i managed to get with the limited time and knowledge i've got on perl

the csv format of both files are the same.

```
"Header1";"Header2";"Header3";"Header4";"Header5"
"Data1";"Data2";"Data3";"Data4";"Data5"
"Data1";"Data2";"Data3";"Data4";"Data5"
"Data1";"Data2";"Data3";"Data4";"Data5"
"Data1";"Data2";"Data3";"Data4";"Data5"
"Data1";"Data2";"Data3";"Data4";"Data5"
```

Comment: Define "combine two CSV files". Do they have the same columns, and you just want to concatenate one's rows after the other? (basically, just stripping off the second file's header) Do they have the same rows but different columns, and you want to append columns? What do you start with, and what do you want to end up with? You might even be able to do this with shell-level commands (no need to write your own program).

Comment: they've both got the same header and the same rows and columns it's just that this is a recurring thing every month a program dishes out csv files and they need to automaticly be added together

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot just do `cat file1 file2 > file3` to concatenate the files?

Comment: `\@{$row}` is doubly redundant. `$row` is already an array reference, you do not need to dereference it, and take a reference to the dereferenced reference. That's just a "double negation" that can be simplified away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is here:

```
open my $fh, '>', $file
    or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
```

If I remember my Perl properly, the line should read:

```
open my $fh, '>>', $file
    or die "Cannot open $file ($!)";
```

The `>>` should open the file handle `$fh` for append instead of for overwrite.

Comment: It does not "work" with the code you supplied, which only takes a single, hardcoded file and prints it to a new file: `output.csv`. Unless, of course, you have already written something to `output.csv` that you did not reveal in your question.

Comment: @TLP: I had been rewriting my answer to open `$fh` (which I took to be the destination file) in a parent block, and the hard-coded input files within that.  The original code seems to have more scoping than needed.  But before I could submit my changes, @Brein accepted my answer.  So, I am right and you are right and everything is quite correct. :)

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Well, I am guessing that you did provide the OP with what he needed, I was just thinking that this question does not make sense, in the context of it being saved for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
opendir(hand,"DIRPATH");
@files = readdir(hand);
closedir(hand);

foreach(@files){
                if(/\.csv$/i) {                                                                 #if the filename has .csv at the end
                            push(@csvfiles,$_);
                                }
                }

foreach(@csvfiles) {
                    $csvfile=$_;
                    open(hanr,"DIRPATH".$csvfile)or die"error $!\n";                        #read handler 
                    open(hanw , ">>DIRPATH"."outputfile.csv") or die"error $! \n";          #write handler for creating new sorted files
                    @lines=();
                    @lines=<hanr>;

        foreach $line (@lines){
                                chomp $line;
                                $count++;
                                next unless $count;                                              # skip header i.e the first line containing stock details
                                print hanw join $line,"\n";
                                }

        $count= -1;
        close(hanw);
        close(hanr);
                    }`
```